# Get response status code using Retrofit 2.0 and RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, android-networking, rx-android

I'm trying to upgrade to Retrofit 2.0 and add RxJava in my android project. I'm making an api call and want to retrieve the error code in case of an error response from the server.

```
Observable<MyResponseObject> apiCall(@Body body);
```

And in the RxJava call:

```
myRetrofitObject.apiCall(body).subscribe(new Subscriber<MyResponseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(MyResponseObject myResponseObject) {
           //On response from server
        }
    });
```

In Retrofit 1.9, the RetrofitError still existed and we could get the status by doing:

```
error.getResponse().getStatus()
```

How do you do this with Retrofit 2.0 using RxJava?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Instead of declaring the API call like you did:

```
Observable<MyResponseObject> apiCall(@Body body);
```

You can also declare it like this:

```
Observable<Response<MyResponseObject>> apiCall(@Body body);
```

You will then have a Subscriber like the following:

```
new Subscriber<Response<StartupResponse>>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {}

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Timber.e(e, "onError: %", e.toString());

        // network errors, e. g. UnknownHostException, will end up here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Response<StartupResponse> startupResponseResponse) {
        Timber.d("onNext: %s", startupResponseResponse.code());

        // HTTP errors, e. g. 404, will end up here!
    }
}
```

So, server responses with an error code will also be delivered to `onNext` and you can get the code by calling `reponse.code()`.

http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit/Response.html

**EDIT:** OK, I finally got around to looking into what e-nouri said in their comment, namely that only 2xx codes will to to `onNext`. Turns out we are both right:

If the call is declared like this:

```
Observable<Response<MyResponseObject>> apiCall(@Body body);
```

or even this

```
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> apiCall(@Body body);
```

**all** responses will end up in `onNext`, regardless of their error code. This is possible because everything is wrapped in a `Response` object by Retrofit.

If, on the other hand, the call is declared like this:

```
Observable<MyResponseObject> apiCall(@Body body);
```

or this

```
Observable<ResponseBody> apiCall(@Body body);
```

indeed only the 2xx responses will go to `onNext`. Everything else will be wrapped in an `HttpException` and sent to `onError`. Which also makes sense, because without the `Response` wrapper, what *should* be emitted to `onNext`? Given that the request was not successful the only sensible thing to emit would be `null`...

Comment: For people looking for the HTTP codes 4xx they will end up as HttpException in onError. the onNext will have the 2xx only.

Comment: That's interesting... I just checked again (https://gist.github.com/DavidMihola/17a6ea373b9312fb723b) and all the codes I tried end up in `onNext` including 404, etc. I used Retrofit v2.0.0-beta3.

Comment: @e-nouri: I just added a paragraph to my answer that takes your comment into account!

Comment: how to handle if the response structure is different than the POJO class . I am stuck with this

Comment: @david.mihola If Build Retrofit via add `GsonConverterFactory`, just as `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())`, How to get the original response?

Comment: I don't really see the point of `Observable<Response<MyResponseObject>> apiCall(@Body body);` - as per the edit you made, to me, it makes no sense to handle error checking when `onNext()` is called kind of goes against the Rx Philosophy - you'll just add complexity of having to check errors in onNext() each time surely?

Comment: Apart from error handling I think you might want to be able to inspect any response headers that came along with the body - that's also only possible if you get the `Response`. I rarely use it too - but I think it's good to know that it does exist.

Answer (score 118):

Inside onError method put this to get the code

```
((HttpException) e).code()
```

Comment: This might be one of the most underrated answer I have ever seen in SO. This is genius. You can do everything you might need to do with the response with `HttpException`. I am using RxJava and I needed to parse the response after receiving a `HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just make sure to check if it is an instanceof HttpException before because NetworkErrors will be IOExceptions and do not have a status code.

Comment: To follow on from @BenjaminMesing said about NetworkError, if you are doing more downstream operators (map / flatMap / forEach etc..) in your Rx before you subscribe then there could be a host of possible exception types, and not necessarily an error on the network request.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Throwable cannot be cast to retrofit2.HttpException

Answer (score 9):

You should note that as of **Retrofit2** all responses with code **2xx** will be called from onNext() callback and the rest of **HTTP codes** like 4xx, 5xx will be called on the **onError()** callback, using **Kotlin** I've came up with something like this in the **onError()** :

```
mViewReference?.get()?.onMediaFetchFinished(downloadArg)
  if (it is HttpException) {
    val errorCode = it.code()
    mViewReference?.get()?.onMediaFetchFailed(downloadArg,when(errorCode){
      HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND -> R.string.check_is_private
      else -> ErrorHandler.parseError(it)
    })
  } else {
    mViewReference?.get()?.onMediaFetchFailed(downloadArg, ErrorHandler.parseError(it))
  }
```