# Retrofit2+RxJava how can I get custom error from server?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I create retrofit2 service:

```
@POST("getTransactions/{page}")
    Single<List<TransactionItem>> getTransactions(@Body TransactionRequest transactionRequest, @Path("page") int page);
```

And try implement it in my Presenter:

```
private class TransactionsHandler implements SingleObserver<List<TransactionItem>> {

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            callView(TransactionsFragment::showProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<TransactionItem> transactionItems) {
            //update UI
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            //show error on UI
        }
    }
```

But in `onError` method I can get only `Throwable`.

In backend side I implement custom error and return it to android. For examle:

```
@Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  private static class EmailException {
    private String message;
  }

return new ResponseEntity<>(new EmailException("Email not sended"), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

But I can not get this `errorBody` from `Throwable`. How can I implement my custom error.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this

```
Single<List<TransactionItem>> getTransactions(@Body TransactionRequest transactionRequest, @Path("page") int page);
```

Please declare it like this:

```
Single<Response<List<TransactionItem>>> getTransactions(@Body TransactionRequest transactionRequest, @Path("page") int page);
```

Also you need to update your observer to implement `SingleObserver<Response<List<TransactionItem>>>` instead.

Please note that in this way only the `onSuccess` method will be called even if the response contains an error. Then in `onSuccess` you can check if the response was successful or not.

Please check [Get response status code using Retrofit 2.0 and RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774940/get-response-status-code-using-retrofit-2-0-and-rxjava) for more details.

Comment: I saw this approach. Does he answer best practice?

Comment: Yes, it seems so.