# How to get https status code in Retrofit RxJava Android?

Tags: android, rx-android

Before I always used retrofit to load data. It's very easy to handle or get status code of the response.

But now I want to use Retrofit with RxJava but I don't know how to handle or get the https status code of the response in onNext method.

```
progressDialog.show();

Observable<ResponseData> observable = apiService.getData();
compositeDisposable.add(observable
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ResponseData>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(ResponseData responseData) {
                Log.e("pppp", "onNext: " + responseData.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("pppp", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("pppp", "onComplete");
            }
        })
);
```

Everyone, please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get response status code using Retrofit 2.0 and RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774940/get-response-status-code-using-retrofit-2-0-and-rxjava)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should wrap your ResponseData inside Response as

```
Observable<Response<ResponseData>> observable = apiService.getData();
```

Then inside onNext

```
@Override 
public void onNext(Resposne<ResponseData> response) {
   int statusCode = response.code();
}
```

and for error

```
@Override 
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    ((HttpException) e).code();
}
```

Comment: you sure there is no adapter/method/object able to get that instead of wrapping ResponseData object into a Response one?

Answer (score 1):

responseData.code gives you the status code

```
   int statusCode = responseData.code();
```

Comment: responseData is my model class sir

Answer (score 0):

for getting status

```
  Observable<ResponseData> observable = apiService.getData(); 
    compositeDisposable.add(observable 
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) 
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ResponseData>() { 
                @Override 
                public void onNext(ResponseData responseData) {
                    int statusCode = responseData.code();
                    // here you get your status code
                    Log.e("statusCode ", "onNext: " + statusCode );
                } 

                @Override 
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                    Log.e("pppp", "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                } 

                @Override 
                public void onComplete() { 
                    progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                    Log.e("pppp", "onComplete");
                } 
            }) 
    );
```

Comment: Sir, I cannot get it because ResponseData is my model class