# Get retrofit onError response using Single

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Im using Single to get some object on success response on retrofit and I'm using `SingleObserver` to get it. And when I have onSuccess, all works just fine. But to handle `onError`, `SingleObserver` hava Throwable, on Response, but I want to get response code, not all error message. How to do this?

```
@Override
public void getContainerPropertyCombination(ContainerPropertyCombinationListener containerPropertyCombinationListener) {
    formingService.getContainerPropertyCombination(storageHelper.getString(AUTH_TOKEN)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<ContainerPropertyCombination>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<ContainerPropertyCombination> containerPropertyCombinations) {
            containerPropertyCombinationListener.onSuccess(containerPropertyCombinations);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your return type of method defined in your Retrofit interface to [Response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html) object. So instead of:

```
 Single<List<ContainerPropertyCombination>> getContainerPropertyCombination(String token)
```

you will have:

```
Single<Response<List<ContainerPropertyCombination>>> getContainerPropertyCombination(String token)
```

This way all responses included failed ones will go to `onSuccess` where you have to decide based on `Response.code()` if response has failed or not.

Same issue but with `Observable`:
[Get response status code using Retrofit 2.0 and RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774940/get-response-status-code-using-retrofit-2-0-and-rxjava/33775529)